# Chrome Extension - Only runs script once I've refreshed page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension that improves youtube functionality by injecting a script. The problem is, if I open a new tab and open a Youtube video for the first time, the script does not run until I REFRESH the page once. Does anyone have knowledge of similar problems/solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Youtube uses dynamic navigation, it's an AJAX-driven site, see [How to detect page navigation on Youtube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](//stackoverflow.com/a/34100952) and [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Answer (score -2):

I faced this problem but I passed the `tab.id` to the `tabs.executeScript`,then it is working fine.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to developing. Can you elaborate/which file would I include this in?

Comment: Simply google up "tabs.executeScript" and you'll see its documentation: the tab id is the first (optional) parameter. However, the answer may be incorrect as it assumes you're using this method whereas you can be using manifest.json. Both your question and this answer show what happens when the question doesn't have [MCVE](/help/mcve) - a random guesswork.